# Why does btrfs /home/ partition keep mounting ro on login?

Tags: fedora, mount, btrfs

I'm having a problem with my `/home` mounted on `/dev/sdb1` on a btrfs partition. It keeps mounting `ro`even after I booted from a USB stick, ran check and confirmed that it could be mounted `rw`. Why would it still mount `ro` when booting on my "real" system?  My fstab line looks like

```
UUID=ba093e47-a5d2-4753-b39e-64413066d9c8 /home                   btrfs   defaults,subvol=/ 0 2
```

`dmesg` shows me:

```
[   36.655791] BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state A) in __btrfs_free_extent:3053: errno=-117 Filesystem corrupted
[   36.655795] BTRFS info (device sdb1: state EA): forced readonly
[   36.655796] BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): failed to run delayed ref for logical 574194106368 num_bytes 16384 type 176 action 2 ref_mod 1: -117
[   36.655799] BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state EA) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2127: errno=-117 Filesystem corrupted
[   50.043538] BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
[   50.043553] BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 992, gen 0
[   50.058816] BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
[   50.058828] BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 993, gen 0
[   50.059196] BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
[   50.059199] BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 994, gen 0
```

I'm running `Fedora 38`.

**UPDATE**

On the live system (`Fedora 36`) I ran `btrfs check /dev/sdb1` and got:

```
$ sudo btrfs check /dev/sdb1
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb1
UUID: ba093e47-a5d2-4753-b39e-64413066d9c8
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 890685730816 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 865299716
total tree bytes: 3958702080
total fs tree bytes: 2745729024
total extent tree bytes: 193478656
btree space waste bytes: 706285981
file data blocks allocated: 2916973436928
 referenced 946788216832
```

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sdb1
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB
Serial Number:    S599NE0M906370Y
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 e0990fd94
Firmware Version: RVT03B6Q
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug  9 23:29:31 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       7874
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       3676
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       39
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   071   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       199
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       82270594760

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  256        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

**UPDATE2**

I ran the check on my other `btrfs` partition from the live system (which actually is the root partition of my system) and this is what I got:

```
# btrfs check /dev/sda3
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda3
UUID: c8ff2d36-e51d-410e-b4f5-64b0b0f4a331
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
data backref 2606956544 root 257 owner 607657 offset 0 num_refs 0 not found in extent tree
incorrect local backref count on 2606956544 root 257 owner 607657 offset 0 found 1 wanted 0 back 0x560968e1b9e0
incorrect local backref count on 2606956544 root 257 owner 615849 offset 0 found 0 wanted 1 back 0x560968134cf0
backref disk bytenr does not match extent record, bytenr=2606956544, ref bytenr=0
backpointer mismatch on [2606956544 8192]
ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 29946847232 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 27541272
total tree bytes: 1149894656
total fs tree bytes: 1045790720
total extent tree bytes: 65536000
btree space waste bytes: 236775382
file data blocks allocated: 42231439360
 referenced 61500862464
```

For some reason, it appears like this partition has an issue that might cause `/dev/sdb1` to not mount properly? Weird but...

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB
Serial Number:    S5B3NR0NB18446P
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 e30b15691
Firmware Version: RVT04B6Q
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Aug  9 23:42:26 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  85) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5877
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2778
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       11
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   072   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       211
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       17129640751

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Do I call `btrfs check --repair /dev/sda`?

**UPDATE3**

After running the above command, my error seems to have been repaired:

```
# btrfs check /dev/sda3
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda3
UUID: c8ff2d36-e51d-410e-b4f5-64b0b0f4a331
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 29946847232 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 27541272
total tree bytes: 1149894656
total fs tree bytes: 1045790720
total extent tree bytes: 65536000
btree space waste bytes: 236775382
file data blocks allocated: 42231439360
 referenced 61500862464
```

and when booting my sysytem, my /home`partiution finally got mounted`rw` again, YAY! That was a weird issue and I wonder what mighht havwe happened....

Ouch just a minute after booting my system, my partition went into `ro` mode again:

```
$ mount | grep home
/dev/sdb1 on /home type btrfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,ssd,discard=async,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

I booted from the live USB again and it appears now like both partitions are healthy:

```
# btrfs check /dev/sdb1
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb1
UUID: ba093e47-a5d2-4753-b39e-64413066d9c8
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 890685755392 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 865299740
total tree bytes: 3958702080
total fs tree bytes: 2745729024
total extent tree bytes: 193478656
btree space waste bytes: 706284856
file data blocks allocated: 2916973461504
 referenced 946788241408
[root@localhost-live liveuser]# btrfs check /dev/sda3
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda3
UUID: c8ff2d36-e51d-410e-b4f5-64b0b0f4a331
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space tree
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 29930229760 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 27525076
total tree bytes: 1149861888
total fs tree bytes: 1045872640
total extent tree bytes: 65437696
btree space waste bytes: 236752423
file data blocks allocated: 41929781248
 referenced 61485907968
```

and it appears like whene I'm on the login screen, my home partition is mounted `rw` and only during loginto Plasma, it gets mounted `ro`,. When I run `$ journalctl  | grep -i btrfs` I get a lot of messages including:

```
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel: RIP: 0010:__btrfs_free_extent+0xb26/0x11a0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  ? __btrfs_free_extent+0xb26/0x11a0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  ? __btrfs_free_extent+0xb26/0x11a0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  ? __btrfs_free_extent+0xb26/0x11a0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  ? __btrfs_free_extent+0xb26/0x11a0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  __btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x7a2/0x11d0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x59/0x200
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  ? btrfs_reduce_alloc_profile+0x8c/0x180
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel:  btrfs_preempt_reclaim_metadata_space+0x97/0x1c0
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state A) in __btrfs_free_extent:3053: errno=-117 Filesystem corrupted
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS info (device sdb1: state EA): forced readonly
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): failed to run delayed ref for logical 574194106368 num_bytes 16384 type 176 action 2 ref_mod 1: -117
Aug 09 21:50:14 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS: error (device sdb1: state EA) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2127: errno=-117 Filesystem corrupted
Aug 09 21:50:19 DesktopRon abrt-notification[3148]: System encountered a non-fatal error in __btrfs_free_extent()
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 992, gen 0
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 993, gen 0
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1
Aug 09 21:50:20 DesktopRon kernel: BTRFS error (device sdb1: state EA): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 994, gen 0
```

How can I get the partition to mount in `rw` mode again on bootup?

Comment: "ran the check"? Which check, with what actual results?

Comment: The line ("ino" is "inode", "csum" is "checksum", "off" is "offset") `[   50.043538] BTRFS warning (device sdb1: state EA): csum failed root 1936 ino 7242 off 1142784 csum 0xa13863de expected csum 0xa13843de mirror 1` shows that the checksum for this file is bad, and that the difference is only 1 bit, `0x2000`. Boot the live system, and use a hex editor/disk editor to find where the checksum is stored, and flip the `0x2000` bit. Why did the bit flip? Is your disk dying? `man smartctl` will you how to check, also `man -k btrfs`.

Comment: @waltinator please see update in OP above

Comment: @waltinator please see update in OP above - how can I find out which file is bad? The disk is a SAMSUNG EVO SSD that's maybe 2 years (or so)  old. I hope it's not bad just yet... added smartctl output above too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think I have figured out that my problem was caused by `syncthing` which is jhust a hunch I had, there's nothing logical I have in my hand that obviously pointed me towards it. I'm still wondering what the issue was caused by in detail - if someone can help me out, that would be great!

Turns out disabling of `syncthing` only made it better but did not fix the problem, i.e. this is still unresolved!

Comment: will post in a new thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754679/btrfs-partition-regularly-becomes-read-only

Answer (score 1):

`btrfs check /dev/sdb1` recommended to expose the root cause. On unmounted filesystem

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, please see update in OP above

Comment: So, very strange. You can swap sata cables between two SSD drives, or use new sata cables. And check if the error stays on sdb or goes to sda